# Identity Server 4 - saving refresh token in datatabase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, refresh-token

I am using IdentityServer4 in .Net Core 2.0 and I am successfully generating access tokens and refresh tokens. I just need to be able to "see" the refresh token on the server side when it's being generated, so that I can save it in a database for some specific purposes.

How can I access the refresh token's value while it is being generated on the server?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Can you please elaborate on how a specific refresh_token can be read while it is being generated?

Comment: My point was that you don't have to read the refresh_token while it's being generated on the server in order to save it. Ids can do that for you. And if you need to lookup a refresh token you can query PersistedGrants (using the store) and query on SubjectId.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thanks, however I am doing something highly customised and I can't use the standard persistent storage IS4 offers. Do you by any chance know of any way to access the value of the refresh token right before it is going to be delivered to the client?
There has to be a way.

Comment: Don't know, but you may want to look at the events: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/events.html

Comment: Do you want to access it while it is generated or you just want to save it in the db, because if the second option - you can still overwrite the PersistedGrant store, to use your own service, and DB. It will still write it to the DB, but now you will control it. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 possibly, the thing is I don't need and don't want to have to build my tables based on their default structure. I don't need to save anything except the refresh token, and that one has to be saved only the way I want and in a table alongside other stuff.

Comment: Honestly - didn't find a way to read it on the IdentityServer side. You can always read it in the client, but I assume this doesn't work for you. Btw - have in mind that if you don't override the default PersistedGrant store, you will receive such message in the logs `You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.`

Comment: And in addition - you don't need to build your tables, based on theirs. I have the same situation in my case, and I just created a table, that suites the persisted grant reqs, override the PersistedGrants store, with a store, that uses my services and reads/writes in my table. None of my tables is the same as theirs, and I'm not using their EF package.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Thanks for your great elaboration. Is there any chance I can have a look at your source code, only about the parts where you create your own tables and use them? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

According to the comments, I think that this will be a useful solution for you, and for others with your case.

I'm starting with the things around IdentityServer itself. As it is highly recommended to use your own `PersistedGrant` store for production environments we need to override the default one.

First - in the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
```

This will implement their `IPersistedGrantStore` interface, with our own `PersistedGrantStore` class.

The class itself:

```
public class PersistedGrantStore : IPersistedGrantStore
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IPersistedGrantService persistedGrantService;

    public PersistedGrantStore(IPersistedGrantService persistedGrantService, ILogger<PersistedGrantStore> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.persistedGrantService = persistedGrantService;
    }

    public Task StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)
    {
        var existing = this.persistedGrantService.Get(token.Key);
        try
        {
            if (existing == null)
            {
                logger.LogDebug("{persistedGrantKey} not found in database", token.Key);

                var persistedGrant = token.ToEntity();
                this.persistedGrantService.Add(persistedGrant);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogDebug("{persistedGrantKey} found in database", token.Key);

                token.UpdateEntity(existing);
                this.persistedGrantService.Update(existing);
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("exception updating {persistedGrantKey} persisted grant in database: {error}", token.Key, ex.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key)
    {
        var persistedGrant = this.persistedGrantService.Get(key);
        var model = persistedGrant?.ToModel();

        logger.LogDebug("{persistedGrantKey} found in database: {persistedGrantKeyFound}", key, model != null);

        return Task.FromResult(model);
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId)
    {
        var persistedGrants = this.persistedGrantService.GetAll(subjectId).ToList();

        var model = persistedGrants.Select(x => x.ToModel());

        logger.LogDebug("{persistedGrantCount} persisted grants found for {subjectId}", persistedGrants.Count, subjectId);

        return Task.FromResult(model);
    }

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        var persistedGrant = this.persistedGrantService.Get(key);

        if (persistedGrant != null)
        {
            logger.LogDebug("removing {persistedGrantKey} persisted grant from database", key);

            try
            {
                this.persistedGrantService.Remove(persistedGrant);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("exception removing {persistedGrantKey} persisted grant from database: {error}", key, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogDebug("no {persistedGrantKey} persisted grant found in database", key);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)
    {
        var persistedGrants = this.persistedGrantService.GetAll(subjectId, clientId);

        logger.LogDebug("removing {persistedGrantCount} persisted grants from database for subject {subjectId}, clientId {clientId}", persistedGrants.Count(), subjectId, clientId);

        try
        {
            this.persistedGrantService.RemoveAll(persistedGrants);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("removing {persistedGrantCount} persisted grants from database for subject {subjectId}, clientId {clientId}: {error}", persistedGrants.Count(), subjectId, clientId, ex.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId, string type)
    {
        var persistedGrants = this.persistedGrantService.GetAll(subjectId, clientId, type);

        logger.LogDebug("removing {persistedGrantCount} persisted grants from database for subject {subjectId}, clientId {clientId}, grantType {persistedGrantType}", persistedGrants.Count(), subjectId, clientId, type);

        try
        {
            this.persistedGrantService.RemoveAll(persistedGrants);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("exception removing {persistedGrantCount} persisted grants from database for subject {subjectId}, clientId {clientId}, grantType {persistedGrantType}: {error}", persistedGrants.Count(), subjectId, clientId, type, ex.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

As you can see in it I have an interface and the logger.

The `IPersistedGrantService` interface:

```
public interface IPersistedGrantService
{
    void Add(PersistedGrantInfo persistedGrant);

    void Update(PersistedGrantInfo existing);

    PersistedGrantInfo Get(string key);

    IEnumerable<PersistedGrantInfo> GetAll(string subjectId);

    IEnumerable<PersistedGrantInfo> GetAll(string subjectId, string clientId);

    IEnumerable<PersistedGrantInfo> GetAll(string subjectId, string clientId, string type);

    void Remove(PersistedGrantInfo persistedGrant);

    void RemoveAll(IEnumerable<PersistedGrantInfo> persistedGrants);
}
```

As you can see, There is an object called `PersistedGrantInfo`. This is my DTO that I use for the mapping between the db entity, and the IDS4 entity (you are not forced to use it, but I'm doing it for a better abstraction).

This Info object is mapped to the IDS4 entity with AutoMapper:

```
public static class PersistedGrantMappers
{
    internal static IMapper Mapper { get; }

    static PersistedGrantMappers()
    {
        Mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<PersistedGrantMapperProfile>())
            .CreateMapper();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps an entity to a model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static PersistedGrant ToModel(this PersistedGrantInfo entity)
    {
        return entity == null ? null : Mapper.Map<PersistedGrant>(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a model to an entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static PersistedGrantInfo ToEntity(this PersistedGrant model)
    {
        return model == null ? null : Mapper.Map<PersistedGrantInfo>(model);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates an entity from a model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
    public static void UpdateEntity(this PersistedGrant model, PersistedGrantInfo entity)
    {
        Mapper.Map(model, entity);
    }
}
```

And the mapper profile:

```
public class PersistedGrantMapperProfile:Profile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="PersistedGrantMapperProfile">
    /// </see>
    /// </summary>
    public PersistedGrantMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PersistedGrantInfo, IdentityServer4.Models.PersistedGrant>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Going back to the `IPersistedGrantService` - the implementation is up to you. Currently as a DB entity I have an exact copy of the IDS4 entity:

```
 public class PersistedGrant
{
    [Key]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string SubjectId { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

But according to your needs, you can do something different (store this data in different table, use different column names etc.). Then in my service implementation, I'm just using the data that comes from the `IPersistedGrantStore' implementation, and I'm CRUD-ing the entities in my db context.

As a conclusion - the main thing here is to override\implement their `IPersistedGrantStore` interface **according to your needs**. Hope that this helps.